# How to address multiple conflicting nouns?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Let's say I have the following line:

> Both the New Jersey Supreme Court and Nicole held that **her** Fourth Amendment rights had been violated.

The "her" is bothering me. How can I address both the "New Jersey Supreme Court" and "Nicole" (for whom the sentence is about) with one word? It doesn't sound right to me for some reason...

Comment: As Daniel said, there is no conflict in your example. You may want to reword the example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict in this sentence. *Her* refers to a female antecedent, and there is only one female antecedent: Nicole. In addition, this is not an unusual construction, and *her* cannot be reasonably understood to refer in any way to the New Jersey Supreme Court.